# Do I need to cover newly planted seedlings when it rains

Tags: raised-beds

There are thunderstorms forecast for tonight.  3 days ago I planted carrot seedlings that were about 3 weeks old.  Wondering if I should put a tarp over them so they don't get pounded.  Total rain expected is 0.17 inches.

Comment: There is a `container-gardening` tag, does that mean the plants are in containers? If yes, put them containers inside for the storm, just to be safe. If the plants are in the soil, do you think the soil will be disturbed by the storm? Then a tarp may be wise, however will the tarp hold a storm?

Comment: Raised beds.  I'll fix the tag

Comment: @mcgyver5 When you say seedlings do you mean they have already sprouted?

Comment: Yes.  They are all about one inch tall

Comment: Do you think the soil will be disturbed by the storm?

Comment: @mcgyver5 Do you think its possible that it will rain so hard that they will break or otherwise be destroyed?

Comment: Sure. It is possible.  In this case they were not

Comment: 0.17 in is nothing. Just a couple of drops, so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad to report that they made in through just fine without any protection and got a good soaking.  Soil drained really well.  Might hail this weekend, though.  I'll probably cover them for those storms

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you need to cover it,but when the rain is weak, you can leave it because it's good for plants to grow , but when it rains hard then you must cover them